# GitPython: How can I pull a remote repository with '--no-ff'?

Tags: python, git, gitpython

How can I translate this in `python` using `GitPython` module?

```
git pull --no-ff
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
origin.pull(no_ff=True)
```

I believe this is the correct syntax for passing arguments in `gitpython`.

Comment: I tried. It doesn't work. I tried also: `repo.remotes.origin.pull('--no-ff')`

Comment: `no_ff=True` should work. It worked for me, kept a watch open for `git commads` in a separate window and executed `origin.pull(no_ff=True)` and I could see --no--ff getting passed for the `git-pull` command.